# How can I remove the duplicated ID's from a list

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have a list with integers.

```
lst = [1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

When I want to print ID's of all elements in the list i'm getting duplicated ID's. How can I prevent it?

**Example :** [image]

Comment: It would be better to post your example code as a text inside `code`, not as a screenshot.

Comment: I just wanted to show the output but thanks for the warning. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

[As sets preserve order in python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) you can do this:

```py
for i in set(lst):
    print(id(i))
```

Since sets cannot contain duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] not in lst[:i]:
        print(id(lst[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if  you  care about the order in list, :(for more https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lst = [1,2,3,3,2,1]
for i in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst)):
    print(id(i))
```

If you don't care about the order, use this function:

```
l = [1,2,3,3,2,1]
def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))

for i in remove_duplicates(l) :
    print(id(l))
```